# Using the same lifetime for the pointer and the lifetime parameter of the struct it points to

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrowing

Consider the following:

```
struct Str<'a> {
    s: &'a str,
}

fn f1<'a>(_: &'a mut Str<'a>) {}

fn f2<'a, 'b>(_: &'a mut Str<'b>) {}

fn main() {
    let s = "hello".to_string();
    let mut a = Str {
        s: &s,
    };

    f1(&mut a);
    // f2(&mut a);

    let t: &Str = &a;
}
```

`f2` uses two different lifetimes, as it would when I elided them, which works fine.

At this point, I thought that the lifetime `'a` refers to the lifetime of `&mut a`, and `'b` refers to the lifetime of `&s`.

And then I wrote `f1` which uses a single lifetime parameter, suspecting that lifetime `'a` would refer to the shorter of the lifetime of `&mut a` and the lifetime of `&s`.

However, this `f1` fails with the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `a` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:21:19 
   |
18 |     f1(&mut a);
   |        ------ mutable borrow occurs here
...
21 |     let t: &Str = &a;
   |                   ^^
   |                   |
   |                   immutable borrow occurs here
   |                   mutable borrow later used here
```

The error confuses me: Why is `a` still borrowed as mutable after calling `f1`?

Why does this fail, and what does the error message supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is `a` still borrowed as mutable after calling `f1`?

```
fn main() {
    //                  scope of s ---\
    let s = "hello".to_string(); //   |
    let mut a = Str {            //   |
        s: &s,                   //   |
    };                           //   |
                                 //   |
    //        f1 borrows a until ---\ |
    f1(&mut a);                  // | | 
    // but it's used here \         | |
    let t: &Str = &a; //  X      // | |
                                 // X X
}
```

The scope of `s` is until the end of `main`. Due to the lifetime annotations on `f1`'s arguments, the mutable reference `&mut a` has its lifetime tied to the scope of `s`, which means that `f1` is borrowing `a` for the entire scope of `s`.

This is not a problem with immutable references because longer lifetimes may be coerced to shorter ones; in other words lifetimes of immutable references are *covariant*. But lifetimes of *mutable* references are *invariant*. That means they cannot be coerced to shorter (or longer) lifetimes.